# updating columns in sql DB using pymssql

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sql-update, pymssql

I am trying to update all rows of the specific column in MSSQL database using pymssql. But I encountered with this error:

> " Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "src\pymssql_pymssql.pyx", line 460, in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.execute
> File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1104, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
> File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1135, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.execute_query
> File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1268, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.format_and_run_query
> File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1806, in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise
> File "src\pymssql_mssql.pyx", line 1852, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException
> pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near ','.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n") "

Here is my code:

```
params = [tuple(x) for x in all_list]
# print(params)
query = """UPDATE dbo.MYTABLE SET KeyWords=%s WHERE KeyWords=%s"""
for i in params:
    val = ("NULL", i)
    cursor.execute(query, val)
    conn.commit()
    print(cursor.rowcount)
```

Params variable is a list of tuples that are going to be the new values of my column. In the column, all values are filled with NULL and I want to update with the Params variable.
Any suggestion?
Thank you for help, in advance.

Comment: I think you want `val = [None, i]`, but I'm not 100% on Python syntax. Side point: `pymssql` is deprecated, use `pyodbc` instead

Comment: To back up @Charlieface (as I didn't know this, though I have been using `pyodbc`): [The Pymssql Project is Being Discontinued](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668)

Comment: Considering that the first parameter is a fixed value though, I'm not sure why it's a parameter. Why not `SET Keywords = NULL`?

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your response. I did not know that Pymssql is deprecated.  I used pyodbc, but I couldn't connect to my MSSQL server. I have no idea how to connect with pyodbc.

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your response. I did not know that Pymssql is deprecated. I used pyodbc, but I couldn't connect to my MSSQL server. I have no idea how to connect with pyodbc.

Comment: Have a look [Step 3: Proof of concept connecting to SQL using pyodbc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15) Though if you are swapping to PyODBC, you'll be better off asking a new question.

Comment: @Larnu All current keywords in the DB are NULL and I want to update them with tuples. As all new values are stored in a list, I used a loop to catch them and pass them in the table. I do not know it is true or not. But the error is related to connecting with the server.

Comment: I, personally, don't use PyMSSQL (as mentioned, I only have experience with PyODBC) so I don't know the syntax, but I would have expected that something like `cursor.execute(query, val)` would map `"NULL"` to the first parameter, which is in the clause `SET KeyWords=%s`; so you're setting the value of the column to `NULL` (or probably `'NULL'`). Though in PyODBC I would have done `cursor.execute(query, 'None', i)`

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for your help. I will try that

Comment: Looks like pymssql wants parameters as an array, and tuples only work if using named parameters, see docs https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/pymssql.html#cursor-object-methods

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for your help. I hope to solve the error.